# Is there an equivalent to Bootstrap's img-responsive in Zurb Foundation?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, zurb-foundation, frontend

I know that foundation has interchange, which lets you swap out individual images with their smaller counterpoints at different breakpoints, however I'd like something that re-scales the images in the way that bootstrap's img-responsive did.

Comment: It's called image sourceset and it is the best way to do it because the images are appropriately smaller and lighter thus faster to download to mobile devices. It's the modern / current way of doing things. https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-youre-just-changing-resolutions-use-srcset/

Comment: All img-responsive class does is applying the following css properties: max-width: 100%; height: auto; and display: block; . I'm not sure what's the answer you are expecting. You can just create a class with these properties and use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create new class .img-responsive with these following style and apply to you code directly. It will make an image scale nicely to the parent element.

```css
.img-responsive {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap .img-responsive is a bootstrap class with this attributes

```
display: block;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

so you can create your own custom one with this same attributes